# get the <T> in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have an `Instrument` class. `Trumpet`, `Organ`, and `Flute` all extend `Instrument`.

I have a "container class" - `Box`, which is generic. In `Box`, I have an array of `Instrument`'s which contain `Instrument`'s of one kind (`Trumpet`, `Organ` or `Flute`).

I also have a function `add` which adds an `Instrument` to the array.

I have a class called `shop`. In `shop`, I have an array of boxes.

I have a function `add`, which adds the `Instrument` it gets as a parameter to its place in the array (it sends to function `array[i].add` - in `box`).

My question is: **If I send an object `Flute` to the function, it has to find the `array[i]` which its T is `Flute`.**

Code transliterated from original below:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flute f = new Flute();
        shop s = new shop();
        s.add(f);
    }
}

public class shop {
    Box[] b = new Box[3];

    public shop() {
        b[0] = new Box<Flute>();
        b[1] = new Box<Organ>();
        b[2] = new Box<Trumpet>();
    }

    public void add(Instrument ins) {
        int i;
        //HOW CAN I FIND THE<T > of the BOX[ i]???;
        for (i = 0; i < 3 && ins.getClass() != ? ; i++);
        b[i].add(ins); //sends to function add in the class "Box"
    }
}


public class Box<T> {
    Instrument[5] arr= new Instrument();

    int lastI = 5;

    public void add(T item) {
        arr[lastI++] = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like he wants a generic box class which stores <Instrument> and then remove something of type <Flute>

Comment: You can't find the type, see [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  The best you can do is check to see if there exists something already added to the `Box` and check its type.

Comment: What about something like `if (ins.getClass() == Flute.class) .... else if`

Comment: @JaredBurrows seems this is OP's habitual formatting style

Comment: I've actually managed to piece together what your code *might* look like from what you're describing in an effort to make it clearer.  I strongly encourage you to come back and add your real code, as you've got some serious syntax errors with your loop.  Oh, and syntax errors in general.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a single method to add items to three different lists anyway?  Your code would be much cleaner with `add(Flute f)`, `add(Organ o)`, etc.  Then you would know the type to add and could use the appropriate list without needing any conditional logic.

Comment: whats your class definition of Flute?   What variables do we have to work with?  I mean, it sounds like you have issues correctly doing inheritance.  I mean, you are trying to figure out which box to place an instrument, so why not have a type defined in the class.  a string or something

Answer (score 3):

Syntax errors aside, there are some conceptual problems at work here.

1. **Your `Box` class cannot add generic elements to it.**

   With the correct array syntax, it would read like this:

   ```
   public class Box<T> {
       Instrument[] arr = new Instrument[5];

       int lastI = 5;

       public void add(T item) {
           arr[lastI++] = item;
       }
   }
   ```

   This doesn't compile because a `T` isn't an `Instrument`, and never will be.

   If your intent is to store up to five instruments of any kind, then two things need to happen:

   - Your generic bound needs to change, and
   - Your need to add a boundary check to ensure that you don't add too many things.

   Luckily, both are easily accomplished:

   ```
   public class Box <T extends Instrument> {
       T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[5];

       int lastI = 5;

       public void add(T item) {
           if(lastI < arr.length) {
               arr[lastI++] = item;
           } else {
               throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Cannot add more than five elements to the array");
           }

       }
   }
   ```

   The lower bound `<T extends Instrument>` ensures that whatever `T` is, it will either be an instance of `Instrument` or a child class of `Instrument`.
2. **Create more than one instance of `Box` bound to different types to make it easier to add elements.**

   The main issue with your `add` function is that you don't know what kind of `Instrument` you're adding in.  If you *care*, then you should be explicit about which box holds what.

   ```
   Box<Flute> fluteBox = new Box<>();
   Box<Organ> organBox = new Box<>();
   Box<Trumpet> trumpetBox = new Box<>();
   ```

   If you *don't*, then you can create a box which will only ever hold up to five instruments:

   ```
   Box<Instrument> instrumentBox = new Box<>();
   ```

   The latter approach may be easier since you're just storing them all into one box, which makes it a bit easier to query later on.

   If you have to separate out the different types of instruments, then you have to use `instanceof` to do so:

   ```
   public void add(Instrument instrument) {
       if(instrument instanceof Flute) {
           fluteBox.add(instrument);
       } else if(instrument instanceof Organ) {
           organBox.add(organ);
       } else {
          // et cetera
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot!

Longer answer: Generics are only a compile time construct in Java and are not available at runtime.

Possible solution: Add a method to you `Box` class that returns the type of objects it may contain.

Note: Usually your code can be reformulated to avoid this scenario altogether. I cannot give you a good advice without knowing why you would require different `Box` objects for different type of instruments. What is your `Box` class supposed to do?